# Why don't the named parameter of my self-build Widget work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to wrap the nested construct of Padding/Container/Padding in it's own Widget so that I can reuse it:

I declare my Widget via:

```
class UpperWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
          width: this.width,
          child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: child)),
    );
  }

  final double width;
  final Widget child;

  const UpperWidget(Key key, this.width, this.child) : super(key: key);
}
```

I want to use it in:

```
class LowerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UpperWidget(
      width:50,
      child: Text("Hello World");
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

When I hover over width, Android Studio shows me the error:

```
3 required argument(s) expected but 0 found
Try adding additional required arguments.

The named parameter 'width' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing parameter, or defining a parameter with this name.
```

What do I have to do, so that `width` and `child` get treated correctly as named parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make them [optional](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters) by wrapping them in braces `{}`

```
class UpperWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
          width: this.width,
          child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: child)),
    );
  }

  final double width;
  final Widget child;

  const UpperWidget({Key key, this.width, this.child}) : super(key: key);
}
```

If they do also need to be required you can include the `@required` annotation:

```
const UpperWidget({Key key, @required this.width, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your constructor schema like,

```
const UpperWidget({this.width, this.child,Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Named Parameter and Optional Parameters are type of optional parameters. Named Parameters are declared with the help of "{}" braces.

For more details visit the [Blog Here.](https://toastguyz.com/dart/dart-advance-functions/)